# What's a polite way of asking "who are you?" on the phone?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, informal-language

Say, you're working in a company. The phone rings and you pick it up. On the other line, someone wants to speak to one of your co-workers. You want to tell your co-worker who this person is.

I think asking "May I know who you are?" is a bit rude? What's a more common or softer alternative?

Comment: "May I know who you are?" is oddly phrased for a native speaker, but it's certainly not _rude_.

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/2970/2033

Answer (score 95, accepted):

"Who should I say is calling?"

Comment: This one (or some variant) is probably the one I hear most often. An even softer alternative might be: "Yes, Joe is here. Can I tell him who's calling?"

Comment: I usually respond with "Who's calling please?" when someone asks for me without identifying themselves, gives the scope to tell telemarketers and cold callers they have the wrong number.

Comment: The advantage of "should I say" is that softens the potential rudeness of demanding that a stranger identify himself and gives a reason why you are asking (because you're going to pass this information along to whomever the caller is trying to reach).

Comment: This is very common, sometimes worded worded "who SHALL I say is calling?" or "Who MAY I say is calling?"

Comment: @Richard Can't that technique be blocked with an equally pushy answerer who responds "I'm afraid I can't put you through unless I know who is calling" ad finitum? If you just won't take no for an answer, nobody can make you put the call through.

Comment: @ZachLipton - You'd be surprised. Most receptionists (and even PAs) aren't strong-willed enough to be *outright rude* to someone on the other end of the phone if that person isn't being rude back.

Comment: @Zach That’s what I always do. People who calls business numbers and refuse to state who they are nearly always salespeople asking to speak to the director/manager/CEO/person in charge. I flat-out refuse to put someone through if they won’t tell me their name and what they’re calling about. If they persist in refusing, then they’re the ones being rude, and I have no qualms about hanging up on them.

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that this only makes sense if you’re passing the call on to someone else. You can’t use this when the call is addressed to you. But in the situation in the question, it is the best response.

Answer (score 50):

As far as politeness goes, the following examples, along with what JeremyC has already suggested, would also be some of the safest ways to ask people for their names when talking with them over the phone:

> Could you please tell me who I'm speaking with?
>
> May I ask who's calling?
>
> Would you mind telling who's talking?

Comment: I find "May I ask who's calling?" to be by far the best, especially in a professional setting.  It is both short and polite.

Comment: @Eric Duminil - Then you ask "Is this a sales call?"

Comment: The first of those sounds very stilted to me.

Answer (score 18):

In my experience, "Who is this?" is generally perceived as more polite than "Who are you?" or similar. I don't have a good reason for it. There are  other more-polite forms, as noted in the other answers, but "Who is this?" is direct, reasonable, and unlikely to offend.

Comment: It's a funny difference. Maybe because "Who are you?" is a direct address, to YOU; we use it when we don't recognize someone and confront them about it. "Who is this?" is more like what you would discreetly ask a friend at a party about another person you don't recognize but don't want to confront. It's used on the phone, but I can also see it being used across a closed door for example. Both cases where you might know the person but don't have enough info to tell; "who is this" is like you're talking to them as "person who might help me know who is on the phone", not as "person on the phone".

Answer (score 6):

**May I tell X who is calling?** has always worked for me. If they refuse, I hang up.

Comment: Does your boss &/or co-worker appreciate you hanging up on potential or actual customers? Taking a message would be a much better idea, especially if the intended call recipient isn't expecting a call and is busy. Then they have to leave their name and number, if they expect a callback

Comment: If someone refuses to give his or her name in response to a polite question, I do not want that person as a customer because he or she  will inevitably be a problem far greater than will be warranted by the profitability generated. The great thing about running a company that provides superior quality of service is that you do not have to worry about grovelling to get inferior customers. I always thought that answering the phone personally rather than having a robot do it won more customers than refusing to tolerate customers who would abuse my employees through rudeness lost me.

Comment: By the way, if someone refuses to give his or her name, just how am I expected to ask anyone to return the call?

Comment: So you own the company, so you're not *"you're working in a company"* and no one *"wants to speak to one of your co-workers"*, and hanging up is definitely rude, so this is not answering the question, and deserves a -1.

Comment: In general anyone who wants a successful business should seriously reconsider hanging up on potential customers for trivial reasons. One rude phone call recording will do more damage to your reputation than you can imagine

Comment: You seem to have missed the context. This is a person who is refusing, in response to a polite question, to say what his or her name is. I ran a very successful business for many, many years, and avoiding rude customers and protecting employees from that rudeness pays dividends.  One of the stupidest things ever said is that the customer is always right. In a consulting business, the customer usually knows he is not right: that's why he engaged your services in the first place. And some clown who is illegally recording me will be having a lot of time to regret it.

Comment: Continued: In my state, it is illegal to record a telephonic conversation without disclosing that a recording is being made. And you may want to continue a recorded conversation with a person who declines to give any identification, but, if so, I doubt I am going to invest in your business.

Answer (score 4):

There's not one perfect answer for every situation. If you don't hear the name the 1st time, just say that. Or, if the caller just gives his/her 1st name, state that you need the last name as well, and the reason why.

I encounter this often. Although I am a native English speaker, most of my callers speak Spanish. So, I am confronted with two problems: First, the need to know the full name of the caller; and second, the fact that I am not trained in the culturally-appropiate way to ask my client's identity in Spanish. (And the most appropriate way to ask this, may vary from country to country, anyway.)

My advice is to listen to the caller, and to respond in a way that seems correct for that situation.

Your tone of voice, and your attitude, probably are more important than the exact words that you use.

Comment: Many Spanish speakers have two family names.  If asked for their last name, they might give you one or the other, not both.  Does this cause problems for you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a polite way to ask this in my language, I think an equivalent in English is "Whom have I the honor of speaking to?".

Comment: That's not very idiomatic. A possible English equivalent would actually be something like this: **With whom do I have the pleasure of speaking?** But that sounds very stilted and rather formal.

Comment: @CookieMonster - yeah, Vincent's answer might very well be a translation of a perfectly correct greeting in his native language, but his translation would only be used by two Englishmen just before one slapped the other in the face with his glove and pulled out his sword. So, Vincent: _don't say that!_

Comment: This sounds sarcastic.

Comment: Valid but rather formal. I've heard this, but not often.

Comment: @davidbak I don't really understand the context. So one brings the bad news to the other that he has married the others lover?

Comment: All comments here are potentially very correct, however if asked with a certain charm you might get away with coming across as a bit of a comedian or a cheeky chappy / gal. You can get away with saying whatever you want if you are smiling. Done correctly, you could brighten someone's day and make them smile with this overly formal inquisition.

Comment: @ooker whether it is bad news depends on one's current feelings about the lover. Perhaps David is implying that the style of language has been a trifle out of date since dueling was a common practice.

Comment: @RobKielty true, but in the OP's context (company phone), it might be weird

Comment: It might, but what's wrong with that? In this day and age taking a phone message is weird. Why not chuck a bit of weirdness back at the caller mimicking the other-centuryness of it all. Taking phone messages was such a common occurrence in the last century that every office had little form based chits for messages that had time of day, name of caller, time of call etc. Given that caller could be cold calling the wierdness could be  useful as a deterrent.

Comment: Sorry for the downvotes (I didn't downvote). But my suggestion for contemporary English is to keep it as simple as possible: "Who is calling?"

Comment: @MichaelGeary No worries, what matters is that some readers including myself learned something ... I consider both my well-intentioned reply as any vote here simply as "freedom of speech", a fundamental right that we should all embrace imo ;).